# Specification of maximumFileSize (Log4Net) and MaxFileSize (Log4J)

Tags: log4j, log4net

I did not find any reference, from which I can know specification for `MaxFileSize (Log4J)` and `maximumFileSize (Log4Net)`.

I want to know what are the **size** and **units**, fields above support as per specification and the specification reference (link).

Comment: For log4Net I have found it :https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.MaximumFileSize.html

Comment: I have now found it for log4j also : https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html#setMaxFileSize(java.lang.String)